# Copiar valor de um input para outro

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Estou precisando que quando eu coloque qualquer valor dentro do input1, esse valor apareça já no input2. Sendo que os dois estão na mesma página, tem como fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode fazer com *jQuery* capturando o evento `keyup`.

Execute o código abaixo e veja abaixo um exemplo funcionando:

```js
   
// JavaScript (usando jQuery).

$('#input1').keyup(function(){
    $('#input2').val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
 <!-- HTML -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input id="input1"/>
<input id="input2"/>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, era exatamente isto que eu precisava.

Comment: Suponhamos q o campo ja tenho um valor quando abrirmos a página, tem como copiar o código no momento em q se abre a página?